# how to create a foreign key with custom name in redbeanphp

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

I have two tables `user` and `comment`: a user can post a comment to another user.

I want create two foreign key from `comment` table to `user` table witch one contain comment writer `user_id` and another contain comment owner `user_id`.

i use this code :

```
$agent->link($TB_Comment,array("comment"=>$comment, "indate"=>  time()))->sharedUsers = $user ;
```

and it create this column in my table `(user_id , sharedUser_Id)`
but i want to rename `sharedUser_Id` to `writerId` ...

how  can i do this? and is there a way to create custom forign key with favorite name in redbeanphp framework ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your example, you can achieve something very close (writer_id, instead of writerId) to what you want easily using [aliases](http://www.redbeanphp.com/aliases).

See this snippet:

```
<?php

require 'rb.php'; // rb 4.2.4 (for the record)

R::setup();

list($owner, $writer) = R::dispenseAll('user*2')[0];

$owner->name = 'Owner';
$writer->name = 'Writer';

R::storeAll([$owner, $writer]);

$comment = R::dispense('comment');
$comment->user = $owner;
$comment->writer = $writer;

$commentId = R::store($comment);

// Schema with user_id & writer_id:
print_r(R::load('comment', $commentId)->export());
/*
Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [user_id] => 7
    [writer_id] => 8
)
*/

// This fails:
$comment = R::load('comment', $commentId);
echo $comment->writer->name . ' => ' . $comment->user->name . "\n";
/*
 => Owner
*/

// But, using aliases, this works:
$comment = R::load('comment', $commentId);
echo $comment->fetchAs('user')->writer->name . ' => ' . $comment->user->name . "\n";
/*
Writer => Owner
*/

// Or, using aliases & magic:
R::setAutoResolve(true); // magic!
$comment = R::load('comment', $commentId);
echo $comment->writer->name . ' => ' . $comment->user->name . "\n";
/*
Writer => Owner
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

i found answer of my question in readbean about page witch was absolutely **Not**.
in last section of [this](http://www.redbeanphp.com/about) page this paragraph was written:

> You should also NOT use RedBeanPHP if you don't like the RedBeanPHP schema policies and you want complete control over the layout of your database schema, i.e. the column names used for primary keys and foreign keys. In this case I recommend to use: Doctrine. If Doctrine is too big for your taste you might also consider a small, active record like ORM written by a friend of mine: DicaORM.

Comment: This is correct, main author of RedBeanPHP here.
RedBeanPHP focuses on hi-speed development and extreme productivity. This comes at a price of course, you have little control over your schema. However, it's possible to just change the names of the foreign keys, RedBeanPHP is able to recognize schema customizations and won't touch them.

Comment: now can you guide me to create a customize schema  in redbean php? this means i must create my foreign keys in my db first? and then use those in my codes?